# Permission to trigger SharePoint 2007 custom approval workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow

I've created a custom approval workflow using SharePoint Designer 2007. The workflow is attached to a Forms library where InfoPath 2007 forms will be stored. The workflow is getting triggered under the user who is creating (creator) and saving the InfoPath form. I've also created a secondary workflow to manage reminders and escalations. In this case, the creator needs to be part of the site collection owners group for the workflow to complete successfully. This poses a permission issue since I am setting item level permission and granting Read permission to the creator once the form is submitted for approval. But the workflow is progressing only if the creator is given Full Control for the Forms library as well as the list item.

I've three levels of approval. Both the approvers and the creator need to have Full Control on the Tasks list and the Forms library. This also poses a permission issue to give Full Control to the approvers and creator.

Does any one know as how to impersonate the user who is part of site collection owner to trigger the work or any other work around to resolve this permission issue?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2007 runs declarative (sharepoint designer) workflows as the user who started it.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdesigner/declarative-workflows-and-user-context)

You can build a custom action to do the elevation of privileges, or use a some pre-built custom activities

http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/

SharePoint 2010 declarative workflows now have the ability to run an Impersonation Step, which runs in the context of the user that last saved the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider using a custom permission level for the list.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx

I would try giving add and edit items without delete & view etc. I would also suggest removing create alerts if you are promoting fields from the form that may be confidential.
Disclaimer - haven't tried this myself.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try encapsulating the code to execute the workflow with this

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    // implementation details omitted
});

to read more on this method chck this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx